# GoLang - termbox: panic: open /dev/tty: no such device or address

Tags: go, ubuntu-12.04, tty

I am coding with Go 1.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine - using LiteIDE (very pleased with it).

I downloaded and installed the [**go termbox package**](https://github.com/nsf/termbox) - built the demo keyboard.go - built fine.

But when I run from LiteIDE, I get this panic - same happens with all the termbox demos:

```
panic: open /dev/tty: no such device or address
```

Any clues would be helpful....

Comment: 1) How do you run your demos?  Is this by hitting some "build and run" key in the IDE or are you doing this is a terminal window? 2) If the latter, what does `stat /dev/tty` say to you when you run it in *the same* terminal window?

Comment: @kostix - ran it from ide, got the tyy error. Ran it now from terminal, go message error package termbox wasn't installed. put the built package into pkg directory by hand, then it worked from terminal, but not from liteIde - same thing happened with sqlite3 pkg - something screwed up with my GoPath I think...

Comment: OK, case is clear now--I've just posted an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, that's completely reasonable: *interactive* terminal applications require, well, *terminal* to be available.  Terminals may be real—[hardware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100)—or virtual (like Linux virtual terminals you see on a typical x86 box when you hit Ctrl-Alt-F1) or emulated (like those provided by xterm, rxvt, GNOME Terminal and a ton of others).

Contrary to Windows, in which running a program of type "console" forces a console window to be created and an application attached to it, on POSIX systems there's no "types" of applications, and if an aplication wants a real terminal available for its I/O it performs a special check for this, and if that fails, the application signals an error and quits<sup>1</sup>.  Very few folks have access to real hardware terminals these days so most of the time emulation is used, and then we talk about the so-called [*pseudo terminals.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal)  Linux virtual terminals and GUI terminal emulators and terminal console multiplexors like `screen` and `tmux`—all of them allocate pseudo terminals for running programs they control.

So basically you have these options:

- Find a setting in your IDE which makes it allocate a pseudo-terminal when running your program.  Some programs are able to do that by embedding a terminal emulator into their UI or by running it explicitly.
- Teach your IDE to run your program in a terminal emulator.  Most of them obey the convention established by the venerable `xterm` and accept the `-e <program>` command-line option, so instead of

  ```
  ./myprogram
  ```

  your IDE should run

  ```
  xterm -e ./myprogram
  ```

  If you're on a Debian system or its derivative, you might get away with

  ```
  x-terminal-emulator -e ./myprogram
  ```

  which is supposed to spawn your preferred terminal emulator program.
- Stop running the code in the IDE and do it in a terminal emulator using the regular

  ```
  go build
  ./myprogram
  ```

  workflow.

I've never used LiteIDE so have no immediate experience with how to do that in it—you'll have to do your own research.

---

<sup>1</sup> Some programs may happily work with or without being attached to a terminal, with shells (like `bash` or `zsh`) and interpreters (like `Tcl` or `Python`) being good examples: when they detect a terminal device available, they go into interactive mode, enable line editing and so on, otherwise they just read the code from their standard input and execute it. Another good example is Git: its high-level programs detect if they're attached to a terminal and if so they might enable colouring of their output and automatically spawn a pager program if their output if about to overflow the single screenful of lines; otherwise they cut the fuss and just dump their output to their standard output stream.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. LiteIDE has a 'run in terminal session' option when you run your code. I'm sure that will work. _Contrary to Windows, in which running a program of type "console" forces a console window..._ - this is important for me. I've been a DOS/Windows guy for forever - only messing with Linux the last year or so - good to have this clarification.