# Starting screen as command in Go?

Tags: go, gnu-screen

I'm creating an app which shall start a script in a seperate [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) session.

*Used compiler:  go1.10.1 linux/amd64*.

My current code looks like following:

```
cmd := exec.Command("screen", "-S", "test", "node /home/servers/test/main.js")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Start()
```

Executing this returns following in the output:

```
Must be connected to a terminal.
```

Also I have tested starting it with specified shell:

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "screen", "-S", "test", "node /home/servers/test/main.js")
```

Same result.

Is is possible to execute the command connected to the current terminal?

Comment: Try [this post](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-users/2016-12/msg00002.html) for some clues.

Answer (score 0):

To start screen you should emulate tty device.

GNU screen code:

```
attach_tty = ttyname(0);
    if (!attach_tty) {
        if (errno == ENODEV) {
            // ....
        } else if (fatal) {
            Panic(0, "Must be connected to a terminal.");
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

You may take a look at https://github.com/mattn/go-tty

Comment: @zekro, [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21858818/720999) I have tried to present a bit more background to this "terminal/pseudo terminal" thing. Consider also reading [this classic essay](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) on what TTY really is.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> cmd.Run()

Instead of:

> cmd.Start()

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things...

First, I believe you're missing the `-X stuff` part that screen needs in order to know what action it should take. `-X stuff <text>` is used to pass whatever is `<text>` into the screen. (i.e. `screen -S test -X stuff "node /home/servers/test/main.js"`)

There is a catch to this one... The example above will only pass the text to the screen. If you want it to actually execute that text, you'll also need to send the "enter" command ("^M") with it. (i.e. `screen -S test -X stuff "node /home/servers/test/main.js^M"`)

Second, it's not a bad idea to include the window argument `-p <#>` to specify exactly which window the command should be sent to. I'll admit that it's probably not needed if you're only using one window with screen, but it won't hurt to use it anyway. Screen numbers the windows beginning with `0`, so `-p 0` would indicate the first window, `-p 1` would indicate the second window, etc... (i.e. `screen -S test -p 0 -X stuff "node /home/servers/test/main.js^M"`)

Lastly, since your original question is about GOLANG... the secret is that you have to break apart your entire command.

```
cmd := exec.Command("screen", "-S", "test", "-p", "0", "-X", "stuff", "node /home/servers/test/main.js^M")
```