# unable to run tview application configured in /etc/inittab

Tags: linux, go, terminal

I am attempting to run an application using tview to show some telemetry.  The application runs fine when invoked from the cmdline as normal.  When I update my inittab to run the application:

```
c1:2345:respawn:/usr/sbin/systatus 38400 tty1 linux
```

That is when I see cannot open /dev/tty, No such device or address, a reference a line number where I am calling tview.Application.Run.  The file / device does exist.

Any ideas as to how I might get around this?

I am referencing this:
[GoLang - termbox: panic: open /dev/tty: no such device or address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21845871/golang-termbox-panic-open-dev-tty-no-such-device-or-address)

even though I'm NOT using using termbox, the problem is the same.  Is it a fair assumption that anything I launch under /etc/inittab is non-interactive?  Is there anyway to disable the interactive part in termbox?  I don't see any public functions to do such a thing.

Comment: Looks like your program expects a fully functional terminal, but you are running it without a getty. I don't know enough about terminal emulation in linux, but I think you are missing a layer in there.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but may be a bad idea.

```
c1:2345:respawn:/usr/sbin/systatus </dev/tty1
```

In any case, I need to disable the default ctrl+c handler so that this remains running.